# Regex Equivalent for +apple +banana +”baby cart” –blog

Tags: c#, regex, visual-studio-2010

I have made application where i run  to get html of a page,when i get it i have to mark the url as useable or not useable depending on different patterns. The patterns are provided in txt file :

#### Example:

```
+apple+banana+”baby cart” –blog
+”apple skin” +banana +”baby cart” –blog
+”apple skin” +”buy now” +jpg
```

The `"` is to tell for phrases than words.

1. html must contain apple AND banana AND baby cart AND CANNOT contain blog
2. html must contain apple skin AND banana AND baby cart AND CANNOT contain blog
3. html must contain apple skin AND buy now AND jpg

### Problem

Can i uses regex in this case? If yes what would be the regex equivalent for the above patterns, so we can use them in the txt file except these and just use it as a pattern to match in HTML....
(**The patterns are not Case sensitive**).

Comment: You want a regex to generalize those 3 (or more) rules in one?

Comment: You can use [Lucene.Net](http://incubator.apache.org/lucene.net/)'s QueryParser class for this.

Comment: @FlopCoder there can be any numbers what i was hoping is to make a pattern with +,- ...Meaning contain +words and donot contain these words...
Or if not possible if i get these patterns as they are they how can i convert them to rejex? There can be any number but always will be + and -

Comment: @FlopCoder Further explaining like if i split the words with + , removing eveything after -.. How can i make a rejex pattern? And thn include the words after - same way...

Comment: It should be easy to parse out the tokens (apple, banana, blog etc.), but to find a regex that would represent all the rules is hard, maybe impossible.

Comment: @FlopCoder there is just + for contain and - for not contain...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A sample regex to at least dissect your search strings (although assuming `-` and `"` instead of `–` and `”`):

```
(?<operator>[+-])?(?<word>["][^"]+["]|[^\s+-]+)
```

This matches a either a `+` or a `-` and the word or phrase that comes after it.

Quick PowerShell test:

```
PS> [regex]::matches($s, '(?<operator>[+-])?(?<word>["][^"]+["]|[^\s+-]+)')|ft -auto

Groups                         Success Captures       Index Length Value
------                         ------- --------       ----- ------ -----
{+apple, +, apple}                True {+apple}           0      6 +apple
{+banana, +, banana}              True {+banana}          6      7 +banana
{+"baby cart", +, "baby cart"}    True {+"baby cart"}    13     12 +"baby cart"
{-blog, -, blog}                  True {-blog}           26      5 -blog
```

You can then process that to build a regex for your content, e.g.:

```
var re = @"(?<operator>[+-])?(?<word>[""][^""]+[""]|[^\s+-]+)";
var matches = Regex.Matches(s, re);

StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
sb.Append("(?i)");
foreach (Match m in matches) {
  sb.Append(string.Format("(?{1}.*{0})",
      Regex.Escape(m.Groups["word"]).Trim('"'),
      m.Groups["operator"] == "+" ? "=" : "!"));
}

var finalRe = sb.ToString();
```

But bear in mind that the resulting regex is *very* slow, especially for longer lists of words.

Comment: Not sure, i am not good in regex but i see only one WORD in the regex pattern ?Assuming you are matching them one by one ?Also can i not use this (?<operator>[+-])?(?<word>["][^"]+["]|[^\s+-]+)
in my code and put the words here one by one? And see the results?

Comment: And in word should i put word with operator? like +apple , -baby or just apple ,baby

Comment: Your name is fairly apt, in that you got me confused as well now.

Comment: I think you have to omit the "+" and the "-", include just the word/phrase itself

Comment: @ravemir How will it know than to check for contains or not contains :|

Comment: I will run it now :) fingers crossed :)

Comment: Sorry, I misinterpreted: the expressions in the Regex shouldn't include "+" or "-", since what you're really interested in is the word/phrase itself. But, in order to be able to distinguish match items for "not match" items, yes, you should leave them in.

Comment: @Joey 'System.Text.RegularExpressions.MatchCollection' does not contain a definition for 'Where' and no extension method 'Where' accepting a first argument of type 'System.Text.RegularExpressions.MatchCollection' could be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?) .......

Comment: confusedMind: Add `using System.Linq;`. Also the code was just an example how you could go about doing that. I have edited it to use a slightly different logic.

Comment: @Joey Error 'object' does not contain a definition for 'Groups' and no extension method 'Groups' accepting a first argument of type 'object' could be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)

Comment: I got the point thank you @Joey but i think it might take very very long assuming i will have 10-200 pattern of rows...And to check with html each time....

Comment: Edited again. But you do have *some* experience in writing C#?

Comment: Marking as answer as it does work, but being a list of patterns it gets a bit slow...

Comment: What exactly *did* you expect or want? This isn't really an appropriate use for regex.